# Convert ereg statement to preg

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Trying to convert this ereg statement to a preg one but having issues.

```
$tweet = ereg_replace("[[:alpha:]]+://[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/]","<a target='_blank' href=\"\\0\">\\0</a>",  $tweet->text);
```

I am getting `UNKNOWN MODIFIER '/'` when trying to convert it over.

Comment: Just added delimiters to the pattern at the start and end but didn't seem to work. Alot going on so got a bit confused

Comment: I got it working as so for anyone else.

    $tweet = preg_replace("|[[:alpha:]]+://[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/]|","<a target='_blank' href=\"\\0\">\\0</a>",  $tweet->text);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working as so for anyone else.

```
$tweet = preg_replace("|[[:alpha:]]+://[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/]|","<a target='_blank' href=\"\\0\">\\0</a>",  $tweet->text);
```